# how I can create unit tests for wix toolset (using LUX)?

Tags: unit-testing, session, wix

Again a basic question. I'm a newbie in WIX and still learning.

I do not understand how I can create unit test for WIX. I read so much documentations... 
The first point, on the wixtoolset documentation :

> 1. You write your unit tests using XML in WiX source files.

But I still don't understand how I create it in Visual studio.

I just want to test my custom action code, I have :

```
var command = new SqlCommand(string.Format("SELECT db_id('{0}')", session["DATABASE_NAME"]), connection)
```

I want to test if I received the good output. For that, I used the session (called with using Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller ) so I cannot use the basic c# tester.

Sorry for this basic question!

Comment: No idea? I'm  a little bit lost..